# Rails search SQL query

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, search

I am trying to make search method in my Rails app, but sadly - my SQL knowledge is rather pathetic. I managed to find guides that have searched text in the description by:

```
@guides = Guide.where(['description LIKE ?', "%#{params[:search]}%"])
```

or in the title:

```
 @guides = Guide.where(['title LIKE ?', "%#{params[:search]}%"])
```

but I don't know how to look in both title and descripton at the same time. Please help me solve this problem.

Additionally I would appreciate any suggestions of sources to learn SQL from for usage in Rails apps (PostgreSQL mainly I guess?).

Comment: Its not the easy answer to your question, but if you want a more robust solution to searching a Rails application, I would humbly suggest standing up an elastic search instance and utilizing the searchkick gem. Although its another level of abstraction and more difficult to setup than a simple search postgres type of solution, it will keep you focused on your app on not on how to search the data in your application

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the keyword "or" in your SQL queries:

```
Guide.where('description LIKE :search OR name LIKE :search', search: "%#{params[:search]}%")
```

About the doc, you can try this website which seems to offer interactive courses about SQL in general: http://www.sqlcourse.com/

This website is about PostgreSQL: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/postgresql/postgresql_overview.htm

Also, `ILIKE` might be usefull in this case (it is case-insensitive).

Comment: Thanks, worked like a charm. And I really appreciate these suggestions!

Comment: If you think you're going to use OR in your queries frequently (though try to avoid it because it is a drag on query performance), check out the squeel gem.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
class Guide
  def self.search(term)
    where("to_tsvector(coalesce(title,'') || ' ' " +
          "|| coalesce(description,'')) @@ plainto_tsquery('english', ?)", term)
  end
end
```

*coalesce* is the kindest treatment in this scheme for possible null values in the database.

This will perform whole-word, non-stemmed matching for the search term you supply.  You don't have a lot of options to tune relevance rankings or improve performance with this naive scheme, but it will work!

PostgreSQL full-text search is quite powerful, and potentially worthy of [more sophisticated options](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/optimizing-full-text-search-with-postgres-tsvector-columns-and-triggers).

Comment: There is also a quite excellent pg_search gem that will construct queries like this for you pretty painlessly as well.  But if you find yourself searching through hundreds of thousands to millions of rows for full-text, definitely check out the "sophisticated" link above.

Comment: That's the 'sophisticated' link above, Don!

Answer (score 1):

**The shortest answer is tag this method onto your model:**

```
def search_by_fields(q, fields=nil)
  sql = fields.map {|field| "#{field} LIKE ?"}.join(' OR ')
  parameters = fields.map {"%#{q}%"}
  where(sql, *parameters)
end
```

**A longer answer is in a concern!**

Using a concern is a great way to provide search functionality to ANY model you choose. Check this out. First create a file in your `app/models/concerns/` called `searchable.rb` with the following code:

```
#app/models/concerns/searchable.rb

module Searchable
  def self.included(base)
    base.extend(ClassMethods)
    base.include(AdapterAcknowledgeable)
  end

  module ClassMethods
    @@searchable_fields = []
    @@searchable_scope = nil

    def search(q, method=nil)
      search_method = resolve_search_method(method)
      self.send(search_method, q)
    end

    def search_by_fields(q, fields=nil)
      fields = searchable_fields unless fields
      sql = fields.map {|field| "#{field} LIKE ?"}.join(' OR ')
      parameters = fields.map {"%#{q}%"}
      where(sql, *parameters)
    end

    def search_by_scope(q, scope=nil)
      scope = searchable_scope unless scope
      scope.call(q)
    end

    def searchable_scope(scope=nil)
      @@searchable_scope = scope unless scope.nil?
      @@searchable_scope
    end

    def searchable_fields(*fields)
      @@searchable_fields = fields if fields.present?
      @@searchable_fields
    end


    private
    def resolve_search_method(method)
      method = method.downcase.to_sym unless method.nil?
      if method == :searchable_fields ||
        searchable_fields.present? && searchable_scope.nil?
        :search_by_fields
      elsif method == :searchable_scope ||
        !searchable_scope.nil? && searchable_fields.empty?
        :search_by_scope
      else
        raise "Unable to determine search method within #{self}, you must declare exactly one search method in the including class"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

**Usage goes like this:**
This will enable the all columns `foo`, `bar`, `fiz` and `baz` to be queried via the SQL `WHERE LIKE`. By joining them with `OR` it allows any of them to match the query parameter.

```
#app/models/my_searchable_model.rb

class MySearchableModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Searchable

  searchable_fields :foo, :bar, :fiz, :bad
end
```

The concern also enables you to specify a scope with Ruby's lambda syntax like so:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Searchable

  searchable_scope ->(q){where("first_name || ' ' || last_name LIKE ?", "%#{q}%")}
end
```

Note the use of the SQL concatenation operator `||`.

Now when we want to search a model that includes the concern:

```
MySearchableModel.search('foo')
```